# LINQ query showing different results

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the following two LINQ queries:

**Query 1**

```
var membersAddresses = 
  (from o in db.MembersAddresses.Include(m => m.Member)
               .Where(id => id.MemberID == memberID)
   select new { 
       memberID = memberID, 
       Address = o.AddressName + ":" + o.Address1 
   }).ToList();
```

**Query 2**

```
var membersAddresses1 = 
    (from o in db.MembersAddresses.Include(m => m.Member)
                 .Where(id => id.MemberID == memberID) 
     select o).ToList();
```

There are 2 addresses against a member. The bottom query returns the correct results whereas the upper first shows the second value as null. Any idea how to correct that query? I want to use the first query as i need to use some customized columns.

thanks

Comment: Just interesting - why you named member address variable `id`?

Comment: you can see the IL from LinqPad for your query http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: have you tried: memberID = memberID => memberID = o.memberID

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but that's a strange mix of query syntax. Usually that would be written as: `db.MembersAddresses.Include(m => m.Member).Where(m => m.MemberId == memberId).Select(m => new { // selections }).ToList()`

Comment: Found the reason for the problem but not sure how to resolve it? Actually while concatenating: 
Address = o.AddressName + ":" + o.Address1 + " " + o.Address2
One of the address fields is Null (i.e. o.Address2) is null in the second field due to which it is returning Null for the second record. It is supposed to skip only the field which is null (like if Address1 is 'abc' and Address2 is Null, it should return at least abc. 
Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the operator `??`

```
Address = (o.AddressName ?? "")  + ":" + (o.Address1 ?? "")
```

A '??' B means, if A is null then take B else take A